# How do I put a variable in a directory in Rstudio?

Tags: r, loops, variables, while-loop, directory

I have a coded loop that is giving me a huge headache. I need to save almost a hundred plots and was trying to do that with a while code.

```
i = 3
while(i<=91){
componentes <- decompose(serieD)
png(filename = "directory\\filename_variable.png", i, width = 600, height = 425, units = "px")
plotfunction(componentes, main = "title_withvariable")
dev.off()
zeros[,i] <- componentes$trend
i = i+1}
```

Note that i need to save the results of the plot function i declared before the while loop in a matrix and that worked out fine in a test without using the variable.

After the directory, i need to save each and every plot with a different name, so it will not overwrite the previous one, which is what happens if the variable is not there. How can I do that? I've tried to make a " "%i", i " but all I get is one plot saved with the number 1, and not the value of the i variable, which is my counter.

I thank you in advance.
Emanuel

Comment: You need to create the filename dynamically, with something like: `png(filename = paste0("directory\\filename_variable", i, ".png"), width= 600, height = 425, units = "px")`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked just like I wanted, just had to study a bit more on the paste code. You saved my life today!